# Neo4j take less time with a query with more complexity (more filters)

Tags: neo4j, cypher, runtime

I was profiling 2 queries on the Introduction Course Exercises on the Neo4j Browser, version 3.5.3.
One of the queries seems more complex to me but takes far less time.

- The first query filter movies to be released after the year 2000
- The second query filters by year again, and also filters by actor Tom Hanks

**First query**

```
PROFILE MATCH (n:Movie)
 WHERE n.released > 2000
 WITH count(*) AS movies
 RETURN movies
```

It takes **26 ms to do 79 db hits** as shown here:
[image]

**Second query**

```
PROFILE MATCH (n:Movie)<-[:ACTED_IN]-(p:Person)
 WHERE n.released > 2000 AND p.name = 'Tom Hanks'
 WITH count(*) AS movies
 RETURN movies
```

It does more operation in less time (**191 db hits in 5ms**)
[image]

What am I missing?

Thanks!!

Comment: Did you run each query multiple times (the timing of single runs can vary widely)? In any case, a difference of only a 21 ms is not really significant.

Answer (score 0):

You should never look at the execution time to compare 2 queries.

The execution time depends a lot the overall utilisation of your laptop (cpu, disk, ...).

To compare two queries, just take a look at the number of **db hits**, and you will see that the second query has a higher number.

A **db hit** is an abstract unit of work for the database.